# Can you match words in a url using a RegEx array?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to grab specific words from a URL using RegEx. I've included the words as an Array but I can't seem to match or filter any of the words in the array. I always get an error that 'filter' is not a function although i appear to be using it much the same as others have before.

```js
function replaceInput() {

  var leadUrl = document.URL;
  var utm_sources = [/linkedin/, /smartbrief/, /email_paid/, /paid_social/];

  var get_source = leadUrl.filter(value => utm_sources.test(value));

  var setUtm = get_source;

  document.getElementById("LeadSourceTitle").placeholder = setUtm;
}
```

```html
<html>

    <head>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
        <script src="utm-url-test.js"></script>

    </head>
        
    <body>

        <h1>Form test</h1>
        
        <p>Populate the webform input with the utm of the url.</p>

        <form>
            
            <input id="LeadSourceTitle" placeholder="This should be replaced with UTM" onfocus="replaceInput()"></input>
            
        </form>

    </body>


</html>
```

Ideally what I want to do is check to see whether these words exist, then add a value to a form input with the corresponding value.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I read your code correct, you are looking for the *path* of an url, not the url itself. The path can be found in `location.pathname`. Using `RegExp.match` delivers null if nothing is matched, and an array (you filter if necessary) if a match is found.

So, do something along the lines of:

```js
const re = /\/linkedin\/|\/smartbrief\/|\/email_paid\/|\/paid_social\//i;
const path = location.pathname.match(re);
const pathFaked1 = "/linkedin/?foo=bar&email_paid=1".match(re);
const pathFaked2 = "/email_paid/nope/shouldpaynow".match(re);
console.log(path);
console.log(pathFaked1.join(", "));
console.log(pathFaked2.join(", "));
```

Comment: Ah yeah that's really helpful thanks! Let me give that a try with my URL and see what i get.

Comment: This issue i have is that the location.pathname won't match the URL.

`var leadUrl = document.URL;
  const utm_sources = /\/linkedin\/|\/smartbrief\/|\/email_paid\/|\/paid_social\//i;
  var path = location.leadUrl.match(utm_sources);
  console.log("The page path is " + leadUrl);`